# Kibana Not working at http://localhost:5601 URL

Tags: kibana

I am trying to install kibana 4.0.0 for windows. I have extracted the zip file and followed the instruction shown in the documentation. After running the .bat file I tried to access http://localhost:5601 but nothing was loaded. How to solve this problem?
Here is my kibana.yml file contents

```
 # Kibana is served by a back end server. This controls which port to use.
port: 5601

# The host to bind the server to.
host: "0.0.0.0"

# The Elasticsearch instance to use for all your queries.
elasticsearch_url: "http://localhost:9200"

# preserve_elasticsearch_host true will send the hostname specified in `elasticsearch`. If you set it to false,
# then the host you use to connect to *this* Kibana instance will be sent.
elasticsearch_preserve_host: true

# Kibana uses an index in Elasticsearch to store saved searches, visualizations
# and dashboards. It will create a new index if it doesn't already exist.
kibana_index: ".kibana"

# If your Elasticsearch is protected with basic auth, this is the user credentials
# used by the Kibana server to perform maintence on the kibana_index at statup. Your Kibana
# users will still need to authenticate with Elasticsearch (which is proxied thorugh
# the Kibana server)
# kibana_elasticsearch_username: user
# kibana_elasticsearch_password: pass


# The default application to load.
default_app_id: "discover"

# Time in milliseconds to wait for responses from the back end or elasticsearch.
# This must be > 0
request_timeout: 300000

# Time in milliseconds for Elasticsearch to wait for responses from shards.
# Set to 0 to disable.
shard_timeout: 0

# Set to false to have a complete disregard for the validity of the SSL
# certificate.
verify_ssl: true

# If you need to provide a CA certificate for your Elasticsarech instance, put
# the path of the pem file here.
# ca: /path/to/your/CA.pem

# SSL for outgoing requests from the Kibana Server (PEM formatted)
# ssl_key_file: /path/to/your/server.key
# ssl_cert_file: /path/to/your/server.crt

# Set the path to where you would like the process id file to be created.
# pid_file: /var/run/kibana.pid


# Plugins that are included in the build, and no longer found in the plugins/ folder
bundled_plugin_ids:
 - plugins/dashboard/index
 - plugins/discover/index
 - plugins/doc/index
 - plugins/kibana/index
 - plugins/markdown_vis/index
 - plugins/metric_vis/index
 - plugins/settings/index
 - plugins/table_vis/index
 - plugins/vis_types/index
 - plugins/visualize/index
```

Comment: is your elasticsearch running?

Answer (score 9):

First make sure that you are using elasticsearch 1.5  and make sure you have started it by pointing your browser to

`http://localhost:9200`

Eventhough if it is not working, then edit your elasticsearch.yml file and add these two lines at the end of file:

```
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: http://localhost:5601
```

Now restart your elasticsearch and then access kibana.

Answer (score 3):

Have you installed Elastic Search 1.4.4 version? Kibana depends on Elastic Search instance.

In your kibana.yml file, there is a configuration for Elastic Search (ES) instance. **elasticsearch_url: "http://localhost:9200"**

If you are installing ES instance in your local machine, then the above configuration need not be disturbed. If you are installing ES in other machine, then provide the correct ES URL. 9200 is the port on which ES runs.

p.s. ES may require java 7 or above.

Answer (score 0):

if you have any proxy settings, Kibana might have trouble connecting.

try

export no_proxy="localhost"

export NO_PROXY="localhost"

as your environment variables

Answer (score 0):

Replace localhost with your machine's IP

exemplo:  yourmachine_ip:5601

It worked for me!

Answer (score -1):

try to run the .bat file by the command line and not by double clicking on it.